# RangeError: Invalid array length in one environment but not another

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am relatively new to Javascript so I would really appreciate someone telling me what is happening/why

I am going through the coder challenges on coderfight. I have the code working in JS fiddle but fails on codefights with a an error:

```
"RangeError: Invalid array length
at matrixElementsSum (file.js on line 25:17)
at _runyckrx (file.js on line ?:28)
at getUserOutputs (file.js on line ?:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (file.js on line ?:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
at startup (node.js:148:18)"
```

The Problem - if the arrays were stacked, and you find a zero at a specific index each array below will have that same index value also be zero

Example:

```
[[0, 1, 1, 2], 
 [0, 5, 0, 0], 
 [2, 0, 3, 3]]
```

will be:

```
[[x, 1, 1, 2], 
 [x, 5, x, x], 
 [x, x, x, x]]
```

then find the sum for every value in the final array

```
 matrix =    [[0,1,1,2], 
              [0,5,0,0], 
              [2,0,3,3]]

function matrixElementsSum(matrix) {
      // Calculate the width and height of the Array
      var w = matrix.length || 0;
      var h = matrix[0] instanceof Array ? matrix[0].length : 0;
      // In case it is a zero matrix return empty array.
      if(h === 0 || w === 0) { return []; }

      var i, j, t = [];
      // Loop through every item in the outer array (height)
      for(i=0; i<h; i++) {
        // Insert a new row (array)
        t[i] = [];
        // Loop through every item per item in outer array (width)
        for(j=0; j<w; j++) {
          // Save transposed martix.
          t[i][j] = matrix[j][i];
        }
      }
     // rows are now cols - if we come across a 0 the remaining values 
    //dont need to be there
      for(var i = 0; i < t.length; i++){
        t[i].length = t[i].indexOf(0);
      }

     //concat multi array to single array
    var merged = [].concat.apply([], t);

    // get sum of flattened array
    var totalCost = merged.reduce(function(acc, val) {
      return acc + val;
    }, 0);  
    return totalCost
    }

matrixElementsSum(matrix)
```

Comment: Which line is the error happening on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most likely here:

```
  for(var i = 0; i < t.length; i++){
    t[i].length = t[i].indexOf(0);
  }
```

If `t[i]` doesn't contain `0`, then `indexOf()` will return `-1`. An array length has to be at least 0, you can't set it to `-1`. Add a check for this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
    var index = t[i].indexOf(0);
    if (index != -1) {
        t[i].length = index;
    }
}
```

You're not seeing the problem in your jsfiddle because your `matrix` has `0` in every column (the `t` array is just a transposition of `matrix`). When you submit the program to CoderFight, they're probably testing it with different matrixes, including some that have no zero in some columns. Then the bug is encountered. It has nothing to do with the environment, just the input data.

Comment: This worked great thank you! Do you happen to know why in some environments the -1 would not cause an error?

Comment: Maybe you had a `0` in all columns in the other environment.

Comment: `[].length = -1` gets an error in every browser I try: Chrome, Safari, Firefox

Comment: jsfiddle runs the code in your browser. What browser are you using? Do you have a link to the fiddle?

Comment: I do. https://jsfiddle.net/toreilly317/v7x10ekg/4/
because jsfiddle runs in the browser and the error came from a node server im wondering if that itself is the problem.

Comment: The problem only occurs if `matrix` has a column with no `0`. I suspect CodeBot is testing your function with a different matrix than the one you used in jsfiddle.